# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Server has no sessions available

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I used to be able to sign into my server via Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.2, then all of a sudden I started getting a "Disconnected from IP address (Server has no sessions available)" when attempting to connect to it.

I'm able to sign into it by connecting to iDrac and connecting via Web Java.

Any idea on why I'm getting that error message and how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error message can mean 1 of 2 things:

For Windows Server installations **without** the Remote Desktop Session Host role service installed:

Only 2 *seats* are available for interactive logon sessions - that means *only two concurrent remote logon session* connected at any given time. This "feature" is in place to prevent people from using a standard Server installation as an unlicensed Terminal Server

If the server does in fact have the RDSH role service installed, this message most likely indicates that you have run out of licenses, so called Per-User CAL's